# Delphi XE8 : Memory Leak with method datasnap server

Tags: json, delphi, memory-leaks, datasnap

I'm currently designing a Datasnap rest server with Delphi. But I have serious memory leaks.

For example, my method *station*

```
procedure TV1.station(ID: integer);
begin


  GetInvocationMetadata().ResponseContent := Manager.xxxxxxAPI.GetObjectStation(ID);
  GetInvocationMetadata().CloseSession := true;     

end;
```

Which call this function :

```
function TSmmAPI.GetObjectStation( const ID: integer ) : string;
(...)
   jsonObject := TJSONObject.Create;   

          stationSelected := xxxxxManager.WorkShops.GetStation( CNCHandle );

          with StatesDB.QueryGetCurrentState( stationSelected.Handle ) do begin

            if RecordCount <> 0 then begin
              ConvertFileToPcom(stationSelected.Ini.FileName, Pcom);


              jsonObject.AddPair( TJSONPair.Create('ID', inttostr(ID)));
              jsonObject.AddPair( TJSONPair.Create('Name', FieldByName(sbStaStationField).AsString));
              jsonObject.AddPair( TJSONPair.Create('Workshop',  stationSelected.Shop.Name));
              jsonObject.AddPair( TJSONPair.Create('Group',  Pcom.Others.GroupName));                  
              jsonObject.AddPair( TJSONPair.Create('CurrentRef', FieldByName(sbStaRefNameField).AsString));
              jsonObject.AddPair( TJSONPair.Create('CurrentState', FieldByName(sbStaStateField).AsString));
              jsonObject.AddPair( TJSONPair.Create('Job', FieldByName(sbStaOPNameField).AsString));
              jsonObject.AddPair( TJSONPair.Create('Order',FieldByName(sbStaOFNameField).AsString));
               //(...), I have 12 addpair. 

              Disconnect;

            end;

            Destroy;
          end;// with StatesDB.QueryGetCurrentState


          result := jsonobject.toString;
          jsonObject.FreeInstance;
        end;
```

You can see, I use the resultContent instead of result from a function because I don't want *result:* in my json response.

So with the report from *ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown*, I see that all my jsonObject and each jsonpair are not destroy !!!

[Result leak memory report, 5501 request from my client application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPukr.png)

LifeCycle from the server class : Session

I use DSRESTWebDispatcher, set in Session Cycle and Timout at 60000.

Someone have an explanation? Did I forget to do something?

Comment: Yes it works, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call `jsonObject.Free` instead of `jsonObject.FreeInstance`

You should never call `FreeInstance` directly to release the object. It is part of internal allocation/deallocation mechanism. In Delphi destructors call `FreeInstance` automatically to deallocate object instance memory.

Proper ways to release object instances in Delphi are:

1. [`TObject.Free`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.TObject.Free) - calls object instance destructor if instance is not `nil`
2. [`TObject.DisposeOf`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.TObject.DisposeOf) - introduced with Delphi ARC mobile compilers and on dektop compilers it calls `TObject.Free`.
3. [`FreeAndNil(var Obj)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.FreeAndNil) - procedure that calls `Free` on passed object instance and nils that reference

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works great! I just discovered Delphi, also I have not acquired the subtleties!

Comment: Welcome to the Delphi :) If you have questions regarding Delphi that do not fit into Stack Overflow you can freely ask them on [G+ Delphi Developers](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/103113685381486591754), [Embarcadero Discussion Forums](https://forums.embarcadero.com/) or [Embarcadero Community](http://community.embarcadero.com/)